# ICM-42688-P read from address not given in Datasheet

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I am currently working on software for a project that involves an [ICM-42688-P](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/495/ICM-42688-P_DS_Rev1.2.pdf) sensor IC.

The FPGA uses a 16-bit SPI interface and needs to read this data block of 16 bytes:

[image]

[Datasheet](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/495/ICM-42688-P_DS_Rev1.2.pdf) Page 60, 13.1

So far, so good.

However, I've encountered a challenge with the SPI, which operates in multiples of 16 bits and the module controller has an internal 16-bit RAM-Primitive. The frame required to access the desired data involves one leading byte (OpCode & Address), posing a problem by introducing a one byte offset in the data frame.

I am considering two options:

```
- Start reading from 0x1C (an Invalid Address), but the desired data won't be 16-bit aligned.
- Devise a workaround to address the issue of the 8-bit offset.
```

Since I couldn't find information in the datasheet, and I currently don't have test hardware available, my questions are:

- Can someone confirm whether reading starting at 0x1C (to provide a byte of offset) works, with the address pointer automatically incremented, despite 0x1C being labeled an "invalid address"?
- Could you provide information on implementing a workaround in VHDL (architectural or any other way) if the first approach does not yield the desired results?

**Note:**

While using the internal FIFO would allow for the one-byte offset, no data structure suitable for my task is currently available.

Comment: Why not reading beyond the other end, addresses 2D and following, if necessary? -- It seems that the decision for this FPGA module forcing you to 16-bit transfers was not the best. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee Reading past the data-field would not solve the issue, as the payload data would not be 16bit aligned. First Byte is OpCode/Data - then a  padding byte is required (e.g. read one dummy) to align on 16bit, and then start the payload.

Comment: Is the FPGA fixed, or can you insert something like a "byte shuffler"? AFAIK shifting a value a constant amount adds nothing to a HDL design, it's only wiring. However, obtaining one byte of a word and the other byte from another word _will_ need additional logic. I'm curious how this resolves.

Comment: @thebusybee I contacted the TDK-Support. If a "invalid read access" is possible, my problem is solved. If not, ill do the byte-shuffler. The Top-Module for the sensor interface has a parallel data-output, so ill have to "deserialize" from RAM anyways. However, I'd like to avoid extra code complexity through "assembling" a data word from two ram words - but its possible.